# numpy array set image dimension opencv

Tags: arrays, image, numpy, opencv

I get raw greyscale frames from an imaging device with no dimensions specified. 
But I know the raw frame is 342x260 pixels.
After initial processing I have a uint16 numpy array (1d array). How can I display the array with cv2.imshow?

```
cv2.imshow('image', npframe)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

All I get is a weired looking window that stretches full height of my screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image size with `npframe.shape`. For a greyscale image this will return a tuple with two elements `(y, x)` like `(260, 342)` for height and width, or for a colour (RGB/BGR) image this will return a tuple with three elements `(y, x, c)` for height, width and number of channels.

You can set your window size from this by first defining the window name:

```
cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
```

The `WINDOW_NORMAL` flag will let you resize the image:

```
cv2.resizeWindow('image', npframe.shape[1], npframe.shape[0])
```

where `npframe.shape[1]` is the image size in the `x` dimension and `npframe.shape[0]` is the image size in the `y` dimension.

Then your `cv2.imshow('image', npframe)` command will be the size of the image.

Comment: thanks, but the array is only made of single numbers, so npframe.shape returns (88920,). As I said, its raw data right from usb bulk transfer, is 342x260 pixels including metadata, and 320x240 image only. I recently wrote the raw data to a binary file and imagemagik was able to generate an image with: convert -depth 16 -endian lsb -size 342x260 gray:raw.bin -auto-level raw.png

Comment: Then you need to take the 1D array and map it to a 2D array since `imshow()` is expecting the named image file to be a 2D array. The image you are getting is probably a single column of pixels i.e. an image that is 1 pixel wide and 88920 pixels high.

Comment: Thanks, got it with "img = npframe.reshape(260,342)". I can now display the image and the window is right too.